# Links decaying without any reason

Tags: ingress

Why are portal links decaying without any logic reason? It is worldwide and MUs are falling down rapidly for both factions.
Do anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of NianticOps sent an answer to this question:

> We had an XMP bug that impacted control fields.  We have fixed that bug but NIAOPS had to ensure all impacted control fields were reset.  This process has created the decay you are seeing in the Comm.

Here is link: [Ingress discussion google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ingress-discuss/BFHNSpity04/UAZUCeY_-hgJ)

Comment: Sounds a bit cheesy ;), but better than a plain rumor.

Answer (score 2):

Rumor has it, niantic lab is leveling up the field before going live.

In my city about 40 fields and 100+ links decayed in about 1 minute, funny enough several links either survived the purge or were recreated soon after.

Answer (score 2):

Things happening for no logical reason are most likely plot-related, and we will see some 'leaked' comment about it on the nianticproject website in coming days.  That was the case with erratic faction totals, certainly.